# '!== false' and '=== true' on strpos with UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, strpos

I'm now using `strpos` to check whether the string is exist or not in an array. The problem is it doesn't return `true` when I compare the string with using `=== true` when the string contains UTF-8 character. And I need to use `!== false` to return my expected result. However, it doesn't matter if I use `===true` or `!==false`, it will both return true if the string do not contain UTF-8 character.

So what I want to ask is why do I have to use `!== false` to compare UTF-8 character instead of `=== true` ? Also, are `=true` and `!=false` the same in comparison and which is better for returning true in comparison?

[The Online Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4de23b11344c11b44207698cf6c11639ed4c76e2)

Comment: You should supply an example of how you're implementing this.

Answer (score 1):

From http://php.net/strpos

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the
>   beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note
>   that string positions start at 0, and not 1.
>
> Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.

Strpos is not supposed to return true, it is supposed to return an integer referencing a position.

Comment: So why only `!== false` returns my expected result?(in the example)

Comment: But both `===true` and `!==false` return my expected result when it compare to normal alphabetic character

Comment: Because `!== false` will match anything that isn't `false` (including integers, strings, etc).  `=== true` will only match `true`.  strpos should never return `true`.  I'm not sure why it works for normal characters because judging by the return value on php.net, it shouldn't.  It should return an integer or false.